# Line ending cannot be regex'd out or trimmed Node.JS

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, v8

Using `process` and `util` in a NodeJS Script in the following way (for me) produces endlines in the resulting string, even after trimming (see: `console.log()` in code below). I am unsure why this is happening?

```
var util = require("util");
process.stdin.resume();
process.setEncoding = "utf-8";
process.stdin.on('data', function (text) {
   var fileCon = util.inspect(text);
   fileCon = fileCon.trim();
   /* and even .replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/, "") and .replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)+$/, "") */
   console.log(fileCon); //((user's input))\r\n (on Windows)
});
```

I have no idea why the line breaks persist in the string.

Help would be appreciated.

**[EXTRA INFO]**

`node -v = v. 0.12.7`

Comment: `console.log` does always append a newline - it's like `writeLn`. Use `process.stdout.write` or something like that.

Comment: Alright, thanks, just in the browser it never did such a thing (displaying the newline escapes). Gave me a headache trying to search for the problem. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: what does `util.inspect` do? If it's reading a file, why not just use the built-in `fs.readFileSync`? Also, what is `fileCon`: a string, or an array?

Comment: @BlueEyesWhiteDragon: Wait, you're saying you get the newline escapes, not the newlines themselves? That's caused by a different problem

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I  am, shall I upload a screenshot of my console?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `util.inspect` : https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) does remove the newlines and replaces them with the escape sequence, before `trim` could do it. Your `fileCon.trim()` call is seeing backslashes and `r`s and `n`s, no whitespace that could be removed. What you need is

```
text = text.trim(); // or .replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)+$/, "")
var fileCon = util.inspect(text);
console.log(fileCon);
```